# Requested JSON parse failed while post json_encode data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Requested JSON parse failed

Result on the post page was somthing like this, how can I revome "\"

```
{\"first_name\":\"Pradeep\",\"last_name\":\"Kumar\",\"profile_image\":\"thumbnail_10000022_1359466283.jpg\",\"category\":\"Restaurant\",\"category_image\":\"icon_restaurants.png\",\"category_icons\":\"restaurants_icon.png\",\"event_id\":\"17\",\"social_users_id\":\"10000022\",\"location\":\"new, Thandla, Madhya Pradesh 457777, India\",\"lat\":\"23.0048561\",\"lng\":\"74.57584440000005\",\"title\":\"dasdasd\",\"event\":\"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p\",\"pic_event\":\"517a1d4a38d411366957386.jpg\",\"event_type\":\"1\",\"day\":\"15\",\"month\":\"5\",\"year\":\"2013\",\"date\":\"1368556200\",\"time\":\"0\"}
```

Comment: How are you printing the JSON string?

Comment: $eventsArr=json_decode($_POST['ed']);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($eventsArr);

Comment: Where is the data coming from, what exactly fails how?

Comment: echo $eventsArr=json_decode($_POST['ed']);

Comment: var edStr=JSON.stringify(eObj);
m.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "<?php echo SITEPATH;?>/socialuser/event_calender/gethtml.php",
data: "ed="+edStr+"&t=<?=time()?>",
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: "json",
.....

Comment: I am sending simple Ajax call with json_encoded data to server that is..

Comment: @PradeepKumar Please add the other code fragments to the question text. It is really hard to find all needed details just in the comments.

Comment: eObj is alraedy json_encode data that is sends from click function from  somewhere.....

Comment: error: function(jqXHR, exception){
      if (jqXHR.status === 0){
       alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
      }else if (jqXHR.status == 404){
       alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
      }else if (jqXHR.status == 500){
       alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
      }else if (exception === 'parsererror'){
       alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
      }else if (exception === 'timeout'){
       alert('Time out error.');
      }else if (exception === 'abort'){
       alert('Ajax request aborted.');
}else{
alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
},

Comment: If I get a data in ajax post page that is already posted on my question, what does it mean...

Comment: @PradeepKumar Nope, you haven't. :|

Comment: This question should be closed. OP created a new question with more detail.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318513/requested-json-parse-failed-while-post-json-encode-data-how-can-i-revmoe#16318597