# Requested JSON parse failed while post json_encode data , how can I revmoe "\"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

```
$valueArr=htmlspecialchars(json_encode($event), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I am sending `json_encode($valueArr)` from

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="event_<?=$event->event_id?>"  onclick='getDetailsEvent(<?php echo $valueArr;?>)' >
```

to this function

```
 <script>
    function getDetailsEvent(eObj){
        var edStr=JSON.stringify(eObj);
        m.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo SITEPATH;?>/socialuser/event_calender/gethtml.php",
            data: "ed="+edStr+"&t=<?=time()?>",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                if (jqXHR.status === 0){
                    alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                }else if (jqXHR.status == 404){
                    alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                }else if (jqXHR.status == 500){
                    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                }else if (exception === 'parsererror'){
                    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                }else if (exception === 'timeout'){
                    alert('Time out error.');
                }else if (exception === 'abort'){
                    alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                }else{
                    alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                var bSend = 'l o a d i n g . . . ';
                m('#load').show();
                m('#load').html(bSend);
            },
            success: function(response){
                m('#evenDetails').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now on this fucntion every thing will work, If I am not using "datatype:"json"", in my local server,
but on the server this was not working..

It will give and error

```
else if (exception === 'parsererror'){
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
```

on ajax call..

On the post page while print the post data, the data somhing like this

```
{\"first_name\":\"Pradeep\",\"last_name\":\"Kumar\",\"profile_image\":\"thumbnail_10000022_1359466283.jpg\",\"category\":\"Restaurant\",\"category_image\":\"icon_restaurants.png\",\"category_icons\":\"restaurants_icon.png\",\"event_id\":\"17\",\"social_users_id\":\"10000022\",\"location\":\"new, Thandla, Madhya Pradesh 457777, India\",\"lat\":\"23.0048561\",\"lng\":\"74.57584440000005\",\"title\":\"dasdasd\",\"event\":\"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p\",\"pic_event\":\"517a1d4a38d411366957386.jpg\",\"event_type\":\"1\",\"day\":\"15\",\"month\":\"5\",\"year\":\"2013\",\"date\":\"1368556200\",\"time\":\"0\"}
```

My Question is, If I got this type data, how can I json_decode, because it contains "\" that will not parse the data on the server.

Comment: echo $_POST['ed'];$eventsArr=json_decode($_POST['ed']);
print_r($eventsArr);

Answer (score 1):

The htmlspecialchars function adds special characters to avoid security holes, one of the characters is the '/' char. I suggest to use only `json_encode($event)`